# What is adding #. to my URL?

Tags: php, url, cakephp

Approximately 0.5 seconds after loading my cakephp application, something is adding a random code beginning with "#." to the url.

This behavior can be seen [here](http://dev4.west-dyke.com/verhuur), the url changes from:

```
http://dev4.west-dyke.com/verhuur
```

to

```
http://dev4.west-dyke.com/verhuur#.Ud03FBcW3RE
```

What is causing this?

Comment: Its not cakephp it is your `addthis` plugin doing that.

Comment: That explains why it takes 0,5 seconds. Stupid I didn't see that. Thanks!

Comment: You can fix that by changing `data_track_addressbar` value from true to false if not required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I commented the issue is not due to cakephp but `addthis` plugin, it basically append an unique Id if `data_track_addressbar` in its config is set to true.

So to get rid of that just change it's value to false.

```
var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":false};
```

Comment: Thanks Rikesh, will answer when possible.